Movie or TV series where a child disappears and the ending suggests that he or she has become a doll
I'm trying to figure out the name of a movie or episode of an anthology series that I saw, possibly on the Syfy channel in 2007/2008.
What I remember about it and I'm sure of: Two brothers fight over a male doll. Something happens and one of the brothers disappears and the parents spend the whole story trying to find their son. At the end of the story, the boy is not found. However, in the final scene, the camera focuses on the doll they were fighting over at the beginning, closing its eyes, implying that the boy has become the doll.
Things I'm not sure of: the final scene could be the mother putting the other son to sleep and then after that, there's the scene of the doll in the same room where the mother was with the son, closing his eyes, implying that he also "fell asleep" because it was night. Another thing is the appearance of the doll in question; it seemed to be wearing clothes with a blue or black cloth coat. The doll wasn't very large because it fit in the children's hands at the beginning of the movie.
Does anyone have any idea what movie/series it is?

That sounds to me like the episode "Scareful What You Wish For" from The Nightmare Room.

That episode didn't involve a pair of brothers fighting over a doll, though, did it? There was just one boy, and a doll that could turn into a boy.

It's not that series, the production of what I watched seemed to be something cheaper, and it didn't seem to have a "horror" atmosphere, even the scene of the doll closing its eyes didn't even seem to be a fantasy story, just the disappearance of a normal child. Thank you very much for your good will in trying to help me.

A (very faint) little voice is telling me "that's an episode of Dramarama from the 1980s" - but I'm not 100% sure
